# How can I conditionally enable a Rust feature based on cfg?

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation

I want to use `#![feature(custom_test_frameworks)]`, but if possible only conditionally enable it via `#[cfg(not(target_os = "custom_os_name"))]`. I would still prefer to have the option to run some tests directly on my host system using rusts libtest, but apparently I'm not allowed to modify features via `cfg`:

Error Message:

```
note: inner attributes, like `#![no_std]`, annotate the item enclosing them, 
and are usually found at the beginning of source files. Outer attributes, like 
`#[test]`, annotate the item following them.
```

Is there any other way to conditionally enable an "inner attribute"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `#[cfg_attr]` to apply an attribute based on some other features.

In your case, you can do:

```
#![cfg_attr(
    not(target_os = "custom_os_name"),
    feature(custom_test_frameworks)
)]
```